# Can you purchase ADRs then sell it to the share issuing country?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges

If I purchase ADRs (OTC or not), will I be able to sell it to the country where the shares are issued?

Answer (score 1):

ADRs are traded in specific exchange.  You can't generally sell it elsewhere.  I.e they don't automatically convert into stock of underlying securities.